# PHP checking/refreashing functions

Tags: php

I have a main document that displays a chatbox. What I want is for the chatbox to refresh on everyone's screen when someone posts a new message.

I've tried many methods, including sleep timers and new functions that call then sleep and get recalled, but this just generates an endless lines of the same or little different data making the form unusable until it errors.

This is my code.

```
<?php

// set error reporting level
if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.3.0", ">=") == 1)
 error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
else
 error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

require_once('inc/login.inc.php');
require_once('inc/chat.inc.php');

// initialization of login system and generation code

$oSimpleLoginSystem = new SimpleLoginSystem();

$oSimpleChat = new SimpleChat();

// draw login box
echo $oSimpleLoginSystem->getLoginBox();


// draw chat application
$sChatResult = '<font color="0x99000">
        <a href="Register_form.html">New Account</a><br>
        login to send a message<br>
        or register for a new account</font>';

if ($_COOKIE['member_name'] && $_COOKIE['member_pass'])
{
 if ($oSimpleLoginSystem->check_login($_COOKIE['member_name'], $_COOKIE['member_pass'])) {

 $sChatResult = "";
 if($oSimpleLoginSystem->check_privledges($_COOKIE['member_name']) >= 2)
 {
 $sChatResult .= "<br>privledge check Working<br>";

 }
 $sChatResult .= "<form action=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF] method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='foo' value='<?= $foo ?>' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Refresh Messages' />
</form>";
 $sChatResult .= $oSimpleChat->acceptMessages();
 $sChatResult .= "<br><br>";
 $sChatResult .= $oSimpleChat->getMessages();

 }
}

echo $sChatResult;

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, your PHP program has finished running by the time the user's browser displays the page. You either need to do this client side (i.e. in Javascript, Flash or Java) or have a separate process on the server which pushes updates to the page.